# How to can I create these menus in css?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes

http://joomla.jogjafile.com/plasma/index.php

I have tried this by giving it border-bottom but I can't get that arrow shape in border?

Comment: Please include relevant code or images in the question. Links tend to break eventually, which will make this question useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those triangles are often called carets. The CSS of the caret class used on that site is:

```
.caret {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    content: "";
}
```

However, they are overriding the display with other CSS but this should help you get the caret. More information on creating triangles/carets in CSS can be found [Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).